# Printing python variables to a txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, calculator, binomial-coefficients

Im currently trying to print the variable div to a txt file I've created called "Calculations.txt"

```
import math
n = int(input("Enter a value for n: "))
k = int(input("Enter a value for k: "))

if k == n:
    print(1)
elif k == 1:
    print(n)
elif k > n:
    print(0)
else:
    a = math.factorial(n)
    b = math.factorial(k)
    c = math.factorial(n-k)
    div = a // (b * c)
    with open("output.txt", "w") as f: 
        f.write(str(div))
```

How would i write div to the txt file? Also I'm looking for short and sweet code because I'm relatively new to python. Thank you

Comment: "``Ignore the indentation``" - no, indentation is an important feature of Python. Different indentation of the same code can change the behavior of the program. Please fix it.

Comment: I cant and i have it indented on my computer thats not ths issue. I currently have to type this on my phone which is the best i can do but I will go over it and manually add spaces

Comment: `from math import comb` `print(comb(n,k)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
 f = open("Calculations.txt", "w")
 f.write(str(div))
 f.close
```

Comment: What if i want print on a new line each time?

Comment: f.write(str(div) + "\n")

Answer (score 1):

Instead of printing, add this to the end of your code:

```
with open("Calculations.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(str(div))
```

Comment: Tried it and theres no output into "output.txt"

Comment: my bad didnt see you specified a file

Comment: did that still no output :(

Comment: did you check your Calculations.txt file?

Comment: Yes i did unfortunately no results